# Can't append to Snowflake table from Snowpark

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to insert a pandas DataFrame into a Snowflake table, however I get

> Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.

when I run

```py
session.write_pandas(df=my_df, table_name='MY_TABLE_NAME')
```

However, when I insert and overwrite the content of the table, then it works:

```py
session.write_pandas(df=my_df, table_name='MY_TABLE_NAME', overwrite=True)
```

Am I missing some option here to append only?

**Edit**

For context, I am running this in a Snowflake Python Worksheet. Before the line with `session.write_pandas(...)` I query multiple tables (via `session.table(...).filter(...).to_pandas()`).

**Edit 2**

Running `session.sql("SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'AUTOCOMMIT';").show()` right before write_pandas, I see that `AUTOCOMMIT` is set to false. I could not find a way to set it in the Snowpark Python API docs. Is there some other way to set it?

| "key" | "value" | "default" | "level" | "description" | "type" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AUTOCOMMIT | false | true | ACCOUNT | The autocommit property determines whether is s... wrapped within a transaction or not. If autocom... statement that requires a transaction is execut... implicitly. If autocommit is off then an explic... to close a transaction. The default autocommit ... | BOOLEAN |

Comment: What context are you running this from? Is it a Snowflake Python Worksheet, a Notebook, or an external machine?

Comment: In addition, which version of Snowpark are you using if from an external location?

Are you performing any other Snowflake-facing actions before you run this? 

Finally, what is the value of `SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'AUTOCOMMIT';` at the time you run the `write_pandas`?

Comment: Hi @Albert, If you are changing the account parameter inside the stored procedure, it won't allow. Instead you can change the account level parameter by running Alter session set autocommit=True; else you can run your python script outside the snowflake and change the session parameters as mentioned in the below code

Comment: Snowflake enforces the prohibition on setting AUTOCOMMIT inside a stored procedure. Note that changing the AUTOCOMMIT behavior outside a stored procedure will continue to work.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Autocommit parameter is set to False your insert not working, You can set the AUTOCOMMIT parameter as True before you append the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.snowpark import Session


s_conStr = {
            "account": "xyz",
            "user": "user_name",
            "password": "pwd",
            "warehouse": "WH",
            "role": "ANALYST",
            "database": "DB",
            "SCHEMA": "schema"
        }
o_snowpark_session = Session.builder.configs(s_conStr).create()

current_db = o_snowpark_session.sql("SELECT CURRENT_DATABASE()").collect()
print(current_db)

data = {
  "calories": [420, 380, 390],
  "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}
final_data1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

o_snowpark_session.sql("SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'AUTOCOMMIT';").show()


o_snowpark_session.sql("alter session set AUTOCOMMIT=True").show()

o_snowpark_session.sql("SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'AUTOCOMMIT';").show()

o_snowpark_session.write_pandas(final_data1, "TEST_INSERT")
```

Above code will set the AUTOCOMMIT parameter true for the session.

Answer (score 0):

I created I worksheet with some code as the following:

```
# create or replace table MY_TABLE_NAME 
# ("calories" number, "duration" number);
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import pandas as pd
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
  data = {
   "calories": [420, 380, 390],
   "duration": [50, 40, 45]
  }
  data = pd.DataFrame(data)
  print(data)
  session.write_pandas(df=data, table_name='MY_TABLE_NAME')
  session.write_pandas(df=data, table_name='MY_TABLE_NAME')
  session.write_pandas(df=data, table_name='MY_TABLE_NAME')
  return "Done"
```

But I was not able to reproduce your issue. I not event needed setting any auto commit. Maybe if you can share more details or review the query history.